# Остаётся возможность использования кнопок при их отключении в Unity

Tags: unity3d, button

Отключаю кнопки при выполнении/невыполнении условий, а они, несмотря на заданные условия, обе становятся внешне неактивными, но при их нажатии начисляются деньги что после выполнения условий и их дизактивации, что до выполнения условий.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class AchMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int total_money;
    [SerializeField] Button FirstTrp;
    [SerializeField] Button SecondTrp;
    [SerializeField] bool isFirst;
    [SerializeField] bool isSecond;

    public void GetCheker()
    {
        if()
    }

    void Start()
    {
        total_money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("total_money");
        isFirst = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("isFirst") == 1;
        if (total_money >= 20 && isFirst == false)
        {
            FirstTrp.interactable = true;
        }
        else
        {
            FirstTrp.interactable = false;
        }

        total_money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("total_money");
        isSecond = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("isSecond") == 1;
        if (total_money >= 500 && isSecond == false)
        {
            SecondTrp.interactable = true;
        }
        else
        {
            SecondTrp.interactable = false;
        }

    }

    public void GetFirst(){
        int money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("total_money");
        total_money += 10;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("total_money", total_money);
        isFirst = true;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("isFirst", isFirst ? 1 : 0);
    }

    public void GetSecond(){
        int money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("total_money");
        total_money += 100;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("total_money", total_money);
        isSecond = true;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("isSecond", isSecond ? 1 : 0);
    }

    public void ToMenu()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
}


    void Update()
    {
       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class AchMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int total_money;
    [SerializeField] Button FirstTrp;
    [SerializeField] Button SecondTrp;
    [SerializeField] bool isFirst;
    [SerializeField] bool isSecond;

    public void GetCheker()
    {
        if()
    }
    
    private void updateUI(){                        
        FirstTrp.interactable =  (total_money >= 20 && !isFirst);
        SecondTrp.interactable =  (total_money >= 500 && !isSecond);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        total_money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("total_money");
        isFirst = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("isFirst") == 1;
        isSecond = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("isSecond") == 1;
        updateUI();
    }

    public void GetFirst(){       
        total_money += 10;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("total_money", total_money);
        isFirst = true;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("isFirst", 1);
        updateUI();
    }

    public void GetSecond(){     
        total_money += 100;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("total_money", total_money);  
        isSecond = true;    
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("isSecond",1);
        updateUI();
    }

    public void ToMenu()
    {
       SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }


    void Update()
    {
       
    }
}
```

Из того что есть в вопросе, можно собрать такой ответ.

Comment: использовал твой вариант, но результаты те же. Монеты зачисляются с отключенными внешне кнопками